# Fix Brightness Slider

Tags: 16.04, brightness, macbook

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 on my 2015 MacBook Pro (11,5). How do I fix the brightness buttons? The buttons register on the system, but the brightness slider does not show and the brightness does not adjust.

Comment: Can anyone shine some light?